Bluetooth Connection Issue on HP Computer with Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1675 Network Adapter on Ubuntu
I am facing an issue with my HP computer running Ubuntu. I have installed an Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1675 network adapter (PCIe – 802.11ax with Bluetooth 5.3).
Problem:
I can connect to Wi-Fi without issues, but I'm having trouble with the Bluetooth functionality. Specifically:
The Bluetooth toggle switch does not work. It shows "No Bluetooth found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth", even though I have a built-in Bluetooth adapter.
I have tried pairing my AirPods (Bluetooth is on), but the system still does not recognize any Bluetooth device.
What I’ve Tried:
I checked my wired headset with a dongle, and it works fine.
However, I still get the message that no Bluetooth is available and can't toggle it on/off.
I would like to use wireless Bluetooth, and any assistance with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
enter image description here

As you're running Ubuntu you should consider deleting this question here, and asking it on AskUbuntu. It's off topic here, but we don't have a migration path to AU. For now, I've voted to migrate it to Unix SE, where it's at least on topic.
